# The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

Tags: c++, winapi, service

I have created a service in win32,c++ . I am able to create the service , but when I try to start it, it gives following error.

[SC] StartService FAILED 1053:
The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

What is the best way to get to the root cause, since this error message is not conveying anything meaningful

Comment: My bet is that you do not properly start up the service control dispatcher, but your post is way too vague and nobody has a crystal ball to psychically debug your issue for you.

Comment: Same problem with a c# empty service with an installation component. Just this vague error on startup.  protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {} is empty so nothing else could fail. WTF

Answer (score 3):

Debugging services is hard. These days I prefer to write a class library that does all the work, a service that just calls one method of the class library, and a test harness (usually a console app) that calls the same method. That way I can run the test harness in the debugger and get most of the errors out of the way.

The two messages you tend to get when your service won't start are the one you just got and the "it started but then stopped" one, which usually means it threw an exception. Yours usually implies a bad loop or an overly long sleep if you're writing a "wake up and see if it's midnight yet" kind of service. But really, running it under the debugger from a test harness is the best way to gain insight into what's happening.

Comment: I'd love to... but my service doesn't do anything, and it still gets this error.

Answer (score 3):

This post is a long time ago but I'm writing this for the future programmers who would be looking for a way to fix.

I had the same problem and spent a few hours figuring out what was the problem.

The error message:

> The service did not....

can be caused when the main function, which is passed to `StartServiceCtrlDispatcherW` through `SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY`, gets returned right after trying to run your service.

The main function that SC runs should not be returned unless SC tells it to stop.

The code would be as follows:

```
void CServiceManager::Start(DWORD _dwArgc, LPWSTR * _argv)
{
    // Your performing code.
    // ....

    ::SetServiceStatus(SERVICE_RUNNING); // Roughly

    // Prevent CServiceManager::Start from returning.
    ::WaitForSingleObject(YourExitEvent, 0); 
}
```

Also you shouldn't forget to pass `SERVICE_STOPPPED` and invoke `SetEvent` in the exit code.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get the root cause would be to check the SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS.dwCheckPoint value. Your service is updating that while it's in state START_PENDING, and with `sc query` you can poll it from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that if you perform a long operation when you start the service, the error might be from that. SC waits 30 seconds for the starting operation to complete, then reports a failure.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I was compiling the windows service using the original MinGW (the old one). 
The problem was solved by simply switching to the latest MinGW-64

EDIT: It turned out it was simply an issue with the service not finding the required mingw DLLs. Compiling with the -static flag also solved the issue